# Can I call a function from a Acitivity if its onStop()

Tags: android

I think not may be I'm wrong is there a different way? the thing is I have a function to access from a activity and I can't define the same function within the service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit ambiguous, but I'll try to answer it anyways:

- Yes, you can call any method (that doesn't take too long) from *inside* the `onStop()`-method.
- But, calling methods on an Activity that is currently in the *stopped state* is not a good idea.

Don't abuse the `Activity`-classes for function-collections! There should only be methods inside it which work **directly** with the Activity itself.

For function collections or if you need to access a class with one state from multiple Activities, consider one of these:

- Override [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)
- Use a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) (recomanded)